# Alter Views exposed filter form

Tags: views, 6

I'm trying to add more elements to the exposed views filter form but am running into an odd problem that is confusing the heck out of me.

I'm using a hook_form_alter call in a custom module to add new select drop downs.  This works great, except that they get rendered out as part of the submit element.

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['test'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'New Filter',
    '#options' => array('value 1', 'value 2')
  );
}
```

Rendered it looks like this:

```
<div class="views-exposed-form">
  <div class="views-exposed-widgets clear-block">
    <div class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-filter-field_node_status_value_many_to_one">
      <label for="edit-node-status"> Approval Status </label>
      <div class="views-widget">
        <div class="form-item" id="edit-node-status-wrapper">
          <select name="node_status" class="form-select" id="edit-node-status"><option value="All" selected="selected">&lt;Any&gt;</option><option value="0">queued</option><option value="1">approved</option><option value="2">denied</option></select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<!-- Select SHOULD go here -->

  <div class="views-exposed-widget views-submit-button">
    <input type="submit" id="edit-submit-wpg-content-bulk-admin" value="Apply" class="form-submit">
    <div class="form-item" id="edit-test-wrapper">
      <label for="edit-test">New Filter: </label>
      <select name="test" class="form-select" id="edit-test"><option value="0">value 1</option><option value="1">value 2</option></select>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?  Why would the newly added 'test' element be rendered inside the submit element wrapper?

Comment: I had the same problem and had to use an `#after_build` function to workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to turn the new form item `test` into a widget by declaring the item in `$form['#info']`

So your code should look like the following:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  $form['test'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'New Filter',
    '#options' => array('value 1', 'value 2')
  );

  $form['#info']['test'] = array(
    'value' => 'test', 
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was having this problem too but didn't realize how to fix it.